# I changed the css tag li by id and not worked

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I developed a timeline however in css I had li {my css li ..} and was in conflict with other classes and libraries.

In order to solve this, I tried to add in html in the tag I read an id and did the same in html ... but it crashed correctly ...

My goal is to stop using attributes in the li tag to avoid conflicts.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

I leave the link with the functional timeline.

In css I have the class li with attributes, how can I change these attributes to another class and still make the timeline functional?

**html**

```
<div>
  <div id="connection" [class]="classOfConnection()" ></div>   
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let priority of priorities" [class]="classOfPriority(priority.id)" 
      (click)="onClick(priority.id)">{{ priority.id }}</li>    
  </ul>  
</div>
```

**css**

```
#container {  
  position: relative;
  display: block
}

li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CACED5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;

}

#connection {
  position: absolute;  
  left: 80px;
  top: 30px;    
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

**Problem**

```
 li {
      width: 2em;
      height: 2em;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 2em;
      margin: 0 1em;
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #CACED5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
      border-radius: 4px;

    }
```

**What I tried and it didn't work:**

I added an id to the li tag and replaces li in css with #id

```
 <li id="time" *ngFor="let priority of priorities" [class]="classOfPriority(priority.id)" 
      (click)="onClick(priority.id)">{{ priority.id }}</li> 

#time {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CACED5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add class to the li tag like the snippet

```
<div>
 <div id="connection" [class]="classOfConnection()" ></div>   
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let priority of priorities" [class]="'priority '+classOfPriority(priority.id)" 
  (click)="onClick(priority.id)">{{ priority.id }}</li>    
 </ul>  
</div>
```

And in the CSS file

```
.priority {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CACED5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;

 }
```

also for the unique class for each priority, you can use Enum for example.

Answer (score 0):

As you have an ngFor that loops through the priorities array and create an li for each array element you can not put the same id for multiple html tags.

So the solution is to use the li selector like this:

```
li {
      width: 2em;
      height: 2em;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 2em;
      margin: 0 1em;
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #CACED5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
      border-radius: 4px;

    }
```

or to use a class instead like this:

```
 <li *ngFor="let priority of priorities" [class]="'time' + classOfPriority(priority.id)" 
      (click)="onClick(priority.id)">{{ priority.id }}</li> 

.time {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CACED5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```